# Send automatic email everyday

Tags: sharepoint-designer, email

I have a list in SharePoint 2010 that contains Active Directory users in one column and their birthday in a second column.  Early in the morning of their birthday I want SharePoint to automatically send an email with predefined text.  I have created a workflow with the predefined text and the condition to send an email to the user if the birthday is equal to today, but I can't get it to work.  Help!!

Comment: Does it work when you manually execute it? If so, have you considered scheduling the workflow, something like (http://sp365.co.uk/2011/09/sharepoint-designer-2010-reminder-email-workflow/)?

Comment: No it does not work manually either...

Comment: Really, I tend to believe you have an issue with dates comparison before anything else. Could you elaborate more on your solution - activity used, how do you compare, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Pause Until workflow action.  Basically you fire your workflow when the list item gets created.  Then set the workflow to pause until the specified date.  Once it continues, have it send the email, change the date to the following year and pause again.  Here is one blog post about it: http://www.smellslikesharepoint.com/2012/06/26/sharepoint-2010-workflow-pause-until-date-and-time/

Comment: Alternatively, if you dont mind doing some code, you could create a custom SharePoint timer job that runs daily: http://dotnetfinder.wordpress.com/2010/07/24/creatingcustomsharepointtimerjob2010/

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure about why workflow failed. However, look on SharePoint Timer Jobs, you can run timer job periodically. Check SharePoint list using SharePoint Object Model and send Email message. Scheduled Job also is an option which you can give a try.

Comment: Which SharePoint timer job?  There are many of them.

Comment: What does this mean?  "Check SharePoint list using SharePoint Object Model "

Comment: First of all I believe that you have access to Visual studio and you can create custom solutions for your site. What I meant was creating a custom timer job which runs daily for sending email alert for birthday wishes. In the execute method of the timer job, you can put your logic such as checking the birth date of the users, sending emails etc. You have mentioned that you maintain a list for the active directory users in your SharePoint 2010.